# 性质 vs 性格 vs 个性 - all mean personality?

Tags: vocabulary

Sad to say, my research has thrown up basically nothing on the differences between these three words, which is a bit annoying. They all seem to be someone's personality. Am I right in thinking that they are therefore fully interchangeable?!

(Grrr, why does Chinese have so many similar words...?! Or - more to the point - why are dictionaries so pants at distinguishing them lol Thinking of writing my own Chinese dictionary...!)

Comment: Should [性质](http://youdao.com/w/%E6%80%A7%E8%B4%A8) ("property", which seems unrelated to "personality") be [气质](http://youdao.com/w/气质)?

Comment: Ah yes, that is probably true. My dictionary gives it as personality, but then the examples underneath all relate to inanimate objects. I suppose the personality of an inanimate object is its properties lol. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Becky stated 性质 = property. It is unrelated to personality

- 性格 = personality
- 个 in 个性 means individual, therefore, 个性 implies 个人性格 (individual personality)